# Displaying various options on a button click

Tags: android, android-layout, keypress, ontouchlistener, android-contextmenu

I want to design  a  button such that when it is clicked, I get various options, from which I finally select one.

This is the same as using the concept as in text messages. For example: If we press and hold a, then we get various options for the various accents of 'a' in small buttons just above/below the button clicked.

How do I implement this in Android? Do I have to use context menus? How do I get the various options in small buttons? For that, will I have to use an OnTouchlistener?

Comment: @YaqubAhmad alert dialog wont work...it occupies the whole screen and comes up as a dialog

Comment: Did you try `OnLongClickListener`?

Comment: It sounds like a [CustomComponent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) task, possibly a compound control using several buttons on top of each other.

Comment: @Muz I know about onlongclick, but my question is how to design the various small buttons to select from

Comment: Oh, you mean you're trying to create something like a popup that creates a lot of buttons? I think you'd need to create a `Fragment` with the button layout you want. A lot of apps seem to do it nicely, with all having the same structure, so I think there's something I'm missing out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [KeybordView.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java) from the 2.2_r1.1 release.  That is the class that implements the keyboard handling.  Pay special attention to the Handler around line 246 and the openPopupIfRequired method that displays the popup for the key if there is a long press.

Good luck.